# Can we have all ICS questions re-tagged?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags, retagging

Why is it that [ics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ics) is used for questions relating to iCalendar? Can we have **iCal** or even **iCalendar** instead? I don't know if upper casing is allowed in tag names, but this could also be **ical** or **icalendar** respectively. We could also use **i-cal** and **i-calendar**.

In my opinion, the **ics** tag should only be used for ICS. You know, Internet Connection Sharing. I think this is a more proper use for this tag. Most of the questions that are tagged as **ics** actually don't have anything to do with iCalendar at all. Most of them are relating to ICS.

I understand that this is a conflict. My suggestion is that we create a new tag for iCalendar questions and edit the description of the current **ics** tag and include "Internet Connection Sharing" in the description.

Comment: Note that these questions are (likely) not about the software iCal (now: Calendar.app) specifically, but about the files and their support in (quoting Wikipedia) Google Calendar, Apple Calendar, GoDaddy Online Group Calendar, IBM Lotus Notes, Yahoo! Calendar, Evolution, eM Client, Lightning extension for Mozilla Thunderbird and SeaMonkey, and Microsoft Outlook and Novell GroupWise.

Comment: @DanielBeck So every file name extension should have its own tag then?

Comment: @DanielBeck What tag do you suggest for ICS then? How can we resolve this conflict?

Comment: The important file formats should have their own tags. `ics` is important through pretty widespread support. And while the file format name apparently is *iCalendar*, we don't use the common file name extension for many other formats as well, so it's consistent. And regarding the ambiguity, [feel free to support my feature request for solving tag ambiguity on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags): "You entered `ics`, did you mean `icalendar-file` or `internet-connection-sharing`?"

Comment: FWIW there's [`connection-sharing`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection-sharing), but it's not exactly popular. Note that I'm not against your request, so far, I'm undecided.

Comment: @DanielBeck But in my view, `connection-sharing` can have several meanings. I guess that's why it's not very popular. While ICS or Internet Connection Sharing refers to a very specific Microsoft technology used in Windows 98, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, and chances are that it's still the same in Windows 8.1.

Comment: "ICS" can also stand for "Ice Cream Sandwich", aka Android 4.0.

Comment: Not to mention...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICS

Comment: @AlEverett Most of those are not relevant in the context of SuperUser. The Android one can be easily solved with [tag:android-ics], but SU probably should not have tags for specific versions of the Android OS anyway.

Comment: @Bob: My point was that ICS, like most TLAs, is probably not sufficient on its own. It will need to be disambiguated, as it were.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestions for this essentially mirror Oliver's:

- Retag all of the questions about Windows' Internet Connection Sharing to [windows-ics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-ics)
- Retag all of the questions about .ics/iCalendar to [icalendar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/icalendar)

However, I don't feel that it's necessary to synonymize [ics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ics) to either of these. Someone will inevitably tag their question with [ics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ics) without realizing it synonymizes to the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going through the questions that are tagged [ics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ics) right now and retag them to [internet-connection-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection-sharing) where applicable.

Questions that refer to the ICS file format, should have the tag removed and should optionally be tagged with [icalendar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/icalendar) or [icalendar-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/icalendar-file).

The [ics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ics) should be made a synonym of either tag. If nobody has a good reason to pick either one of the tags as the synonym target, I would pick [icalendar-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/icalendar-file).

Comment: We can't use `internet-connection-sharing`, as it violates the 25 character maximum length.

Comment: @tapped-out: Ugh, that sucks :P How about `windows-ics` then?

Answer (score 0):

.ics for an extension, ICS for internet connection sharing, and The Program name for the program that any .ics discussion is about.

Straw man argument tossed out.

I think All extensions should be include the DOT  .ics  when searching for an extension. If it doesn't have the dot it will come up with many many possible 3 digit abbreviated terms in many fields.  If the SU extensions are to be found, then they should be extensions not abbreviations for anything.

Comment: A) `ics` refers to the [iCalendar file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/iCalendar) supported by MS Outlook, Lotus Notes, Novell GroupWise, Lightning for Thunderbird, and Apple Mail, not a $2 app by some random developer. Read the tag description and/or Wikipedia. Nice straw man argument there. B) Almost all other file name extension tags (`pdf`, `rar`, `zip`, `doc`, `docx`, `xls`, `xlsx`, `swf`, `exe`, `mkv`, `mp4`, `mp3`, `3gp`, `vob`, `m4a`, `msi`, `wmv`, `wma`) have tags without a leading dot, making your "*make it a real extention with the dot*" suggestion completely baseless.

Comment: Hey its not my fault that the way it was done was wrong from the start.  Extentions are extentions and Abreviations that can mean anything dont have a dot.  I certannly wouldnt have set it up that way myself.  It is already bad enough to find out what program an extention is for.